# How to get wifi to reconnect automatically?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, thinkpad

Hardware is a Lenovo Thinkpad 10.  Operating System is Windows 10 (32-bit).  Upon boot, the machine will connect to wireless just fine.  However, if the wireless drops for any reason (such as signal strength), the wifi will not function until a system restart is done (a couple of times disabling/re-enabling the adaptor has worked, but usually it does not).

Ideally, it would automatically reconnect to the wireless when back in range, but if even manually reconnecting would work it would be better than having to shutdown/startup again.  Any ideas on configuration settings to check?  So far I ran across one that tells it to automatically connect to "open" networks.  Turning that off has made it harder to lose connectivity, but still once connectivity is lost it will not come back.

Comment: Have you check for and installed any updated drivers related to this issue?

Comment: There are no driver updates available at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While no driver updates were available at the time (previous driver was March 25th, 2015), the Lenovo updates system just presented me with a "hotkey" update.  Upon installing said "hotkey update", the wifi now reconnects as needed to our wifi!